# От того - слитно или раздельно

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Слитное или раздельное написание "от//того" требуется в данном предложении?

Он должен был умереть от того, что ничего более не мог совершить, и от того, что свершил всё, что мог; он должен был умереть от того, что его миссия была закончена; от того, что история и ход развития выжали из него всё, что было им нужно; от того, что он им не был нужен более.

Answer (score 1):

Задавайте в таких случаях вопрос ПО КАКОЙ ПРИЧИНЕ?

Если ответить можно с ПОТОМУ ЧТО, значит, пишем слитно: ОТТОГО ЧТО - причинный союз.

*Он должен был умереть ПО КАКОЙ ПРИЧИНЕ? оттого, что (= потому что) ничего более не мог совершить, и оттого, что свершил всё, что мог; он должен был умереть оттого, что его миссия была закончена; оттого, что история и ход развития выжали из него всё, что было им нужно; оттого, что он им не был нужен более.*

Еще примеры [Оттого, что и от того, что](https://popravilam.com/blog/173-ottogo-chto-ili-ot-togo-chto.html):

*Паузы возникают оттого, что у гостей нет общих тем.* — По какой причине возникают? Возникают потому, что нет общих тем. Слитное написание.

*Независимо от того, что думают родители, Владик решил стать военным.* — Нет значения причины, ударение падает на «что» — раздельное написание.

Comment: Екатерина, а вам не кажется, что это очень зыбкий критерий? Вот насчет *"умереть, оттого, что история и.. ход.. выжали"* - ну как минимум неоднозначно. Что выжали - от того и умер. Чем не вариант?!

Comment: Спасибо, да, неоднозначность присутствует; кроме того, наличествует и конкретное действие, это путает картину. Но всё же склоняюсь к ответу Екатерины.